# Mysql - how to add remote connection IP range?

Tags: mysql

I have recently started using phpstorm and I'm trying to add data source.

It seems I cannot because my mysql server doesnt accept remote connections.

How do I add IP ranges so it may accept them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to grant privileges to your mysql user for access from your local IP, for example

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
ON database.*
TO 'foo'@'remotehost';
```

you can also use wildcards (%) to ip or hostname

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
ON database.*
TO 'foo'@'123.123.%.%';
```

or

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
ON database.*
TO 'foo'@'%.foobar.com';
```

Refer to the docs for details, below mysql 5.5 refman
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html#grant-database-privileges